# Average calculator ' possible lossy conversion from float to int" - Java assignment

Tags: java, arrays

Firstly, this is a homework assignment. I apologize. I'm just at my wits end and it's almost due.

I have a program here to accept a number (How many graded assignments I have) then I input the grades of each assignment. So like

```
How many graded assignments do you have? : 5 
Please enter grade : 95 
Please enter grade : 72 
Please enter grade : 86 
Please enter grade : 93 
Please enter grade : 87
Your average is 86.6
```

I actually have a working program for this. The problem is, I used integers and a double. Before submitting, I found the assignment calls for an array of floats. I cannot for the life of me get the float version working.  I tried to modify my existing code but no matter what, I get the "possible lossy conversion from float to int" error 3 times.

I'll upload both versions. Starting with the working int/double then the float version.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class AverageCalc
{

   public static void main(String[] args)

  {

    String input, numberofGrades;
    int scoreSum;
    double data[];
    double sum = 0, average = 0;

    System.out.println("\tGrade Average Calculator");
    numberofGrades = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many assignments have been graded?");
    scoreSum = Integer.parseInt(numberofGrades);
    data = new double[scoreSum];

    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
    {
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your grade for each assignment");
        data[i] = Double.parseDouble(input);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)

    {

        sum += data[i];

        average = sum / data.length;

    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null," The Average is: " + average, "Result",
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
}
 }
```

That one works so I tried to convert it to floats. Keep in mind, I've been experimenting a lot on this code, trying different things, like 0.0, 0.0f, etc etc so it may be more off than it should be.

```
String input, numberofGrades;
    float scoreSum;
    float data[];
    float sum = 0.0f, average = 0.0f;

    System.out.println("\tGrade Average Calculator");
    numberofGrades = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("How many assignments have been graded?");
    scoreSum = Float.parseFloat(numberofGrades);
    data = new float[scoreSum];

    for (float f = 0.0f; f < data.length; f++)
    {
        input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter your grade for each assignment");
        data[f] = Float.parseFloat(input);
    }

    for (float f = 0.0f; f < data.length; f++)

    {

        sum += data[f];

        average = sum / data.length;
```

No matter what I do, even making scoreSum a float (which is illogical because the amount of graded assignments will always be an integer) , I get the "lossy" message for lines

```
data = new float[scoreSum];

data[f] = Float.parseFloat(input);

sum += data[f];
```

I have no idea what to do at this point. I'm just trying to finish the assignment, get out of the class, never take a coding elective again lol. Leave it to the pros.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: At quick glance, and running your code, it seems to work. If you need the inputs as `floats`, `data[i] = Float.parseFloat(input);` works. What else is not working? I don't get any `"lossy"` messages

Comment: The first block of code is my original using ints and doubles. It works fine. But under that I posted my version with floats. That is the one that gives me three "lossy" compile errors. @davedwards

Comment: Ok cool, I think the "array of floats" requirement is required only for the values "inputted" by the user, not for the counters in the `for`-loops. So your original version should be correct, if you only need to change that one line `data[i] = Float.parseFloat(input);`

Comment: Actually you helped me out. I got it working. That was what I did not change properly. I took  "data[i] = Double.parseDouble(input)" and changed it to "data[i] = Float.parseFloat(input)" and I took "double data[]" and changed it to "float data[i]" and it's working now. Thanks @davedwards ! You're the best man, I had been stressing over this cause the book did not actually cover us using floats in an array, just integers.

Comment: awesome glad you got it done 

Comment: @Michael you got it done? your enclosed code not mentioned that kind of thing you said here? Good is good ~